# Powershell Script to temporarily disable SharePoint subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sub-site, lock

I tried using the following script to disable one of my sub-sites:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential xyz@contoso.com
```

I get the following error:

**The site is not properly formed.**

It seems that this script only works at site collection level. Do we have any script which would work at sub site level as well? Or any other suggestion how I could disable this site.

Comment: could you please add ur complete code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no functionality available at subsite site level, locking available only at site collection level.

What you can do as a workaround,

- Go to to Sub-site permission setting from Site settings
- Stop the inheritance
- Remove all users /groups or change their permission level. If you want to restrict for short time then make sure you copy the permission somewhere else before.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the above, you might like to also confirm theres no sites below the subsite that you dont want locked. If there is, break inheritence first.